# Magento wrongly redirects https!

Tags: nginx, ssl, varnish, https

I have a big problem with one magento installation.
It is a Magento Version 1.8.0.0 running on apache with php5-fpm, a Varnish cache in front and nginx as ssl reverse proxy.

If I open any URL using https, magento redirects to `http://shopurl/index.php/`
This then redirects to `Location:/`
I switched Web server rewrites and rediect to startpage off in the settings, no change.
I created a dbg.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_SERVER);
echo "\n\n\ngetenv('HTTPS'): ";
print_r(getenv('HTTPS'));
```

The result is: [this](https://gist.github.com/J0s3f/b253e77c04c4d3dd78f3)

You can see, that `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` is set.

I don't know where else I can look to find the problem.
For now, I changed the secure url to `http://`, because users where not able to login or purchase.
But this can't be permanent.

Any Ideas how I can find out what is wrong?

If I activate `proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;` in nginx, so it changes redirects to `http://` to `https://`, a redirection loop endlessly redirecting to `https://domain/index.php/` is the result.

The apache rewrite log for `https://domain/test` shows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2014:12:20:14 +0000] [domain/sid#7f6236faac58][rid#7f61439ff0a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/magento/] rewrite 'test' -> 'index.php'
```

So it seems that the redirect happens inside the magento PHP code...

Answer (score 7):

try to paste this in your index.php

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

or

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

if i understand you right. or your nginx config is wrong.

Comment: amazing answer sir!

Answer (score 3):

Had exactly the same issue, but on Nginx. Resolved by adding the following into the nginx domain .conf file.

fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

Answer (score 1):

Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure

Check if "Base Link URL" is set with "https".

Check that  "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" is set to Yes.

Comment: Base link url has http and Use secure urls in frontent is Yes

Comment: I you want your site working with https you should define "Base Link URL" in `System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure`  with "https", otherwise it will redirect you to "http".

Comment: no, if I do that, I get an infinite redirection loop!

Answer (score 0):

***Using Database:***

- Open `core_config_data` table in your database.
- Search for `web/secure/offloader_header`
- Change its value to `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`
- Save and flush the cache.

***If admin is working:***

- Open Stores > Settings > Configurations > General > Web
- Open Tab `Base URLs (Secure)`
- Update the value of `Offloader header` to `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO`

Try using `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` if it does not work then use
`SSL_OFFLOADED`