# pound varnish nginx ssl redirect loop

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, https, varnish

i am trying to put nginx as a application server for magento with varnish being on top and pound as ssl termination , problem is the whole setup result to nasty redirect loop. 
using apache and adding "SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on" in .htacess save the day . still need to run it on nginx, can some one please provide the solution for the same .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento wrongly redirects https!](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/magento-wrongly-redirects-https)

Comment: https://wiki.deimos.fr/Nginx_%2B_Varnish_:_Cache_even_in_HTTPS_by_offloading_SSL

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please share more information about your current setup. "save the day" sound like you managed to solve the problem. So what exactly is your configuration right now and how does the system misbehave?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to overcomplicate things so much? Get rid of pound. Use Nginx for SSL termination:

SSL request flow: **Nginx -> Varnish -> Nginx (80) -> PHP-FPM**

Normal request: **Varnish -> Nginx (80) -> PHP-FPM**