# Mixed Content: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: magento-2.1

I have just switched our sites over to use SSL and they are working however I am seeing this in the console...

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mysite.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.mysite.co.uk/customer/section/load/?sections=cart&update_section_id=false&_=1506870648904'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js:86 Uncaught Error: [object Object]
at Object.<anonymous> (/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/Magento_Customer/js/customer-data.js:86)
at fire (/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/jquery.js:3099)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/jquery.js:3211)
at done (/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/jquery.js:9312)
at XMLHttpRequest.callback (/pub/static/frontend/name/theme/en_GB/jquery.js:9720)
```

I also have a separate store view which is also using SSL and they are setup pretty much identical, yet that site does not have this error.

All of my urls in **admin>configuration>web** are **`https`**

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Magento 2.1.4

Comment: Have you check your core_config_data table  and  check any value at **value** coloumn exits with `http://www.mysite.co.uk/`?

Comment: Lifesaver thank you - there was still a http entry for web/secure/base_link_url in core_config_data - thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You should check this

This 4 fields values at  core_config_data database table.

- Base URL: `web/unsecure/base_url`
- Base Link URL: `web/unsecure/base_link_url`
- Secure Base URL: `web/secure/base_url`
- Secure Base Link URL: `web/secure/base_link_url`

Check this 4 field value should start with `https`

[image]

Comment: Thanks - in admin they looked correct but in the database it didnt - weird - solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to paste this in your index.php

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

or

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

got it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19489/73429).

Happy Coding