# Magento 2 : Mixed Content Error Block HTTP Request an HTTPS page

Tags: magento2, htaccess, apache2

When I call the third party HTTP URL in my page. Then, I face the below error.

How can I solve it?

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://*******************' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://***************************'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Refer the link you can help.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195440/mixed-content-this-request-has-been-blocked-the-content-must-be-served-over-ht?rq=1

Comment: I have already done this process. but It's not working yet.

Comment: refer this url to https - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: I have try using add "<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">" in head but It's not worked. And for the other one "copy the content of URL", I  can't accept this way because I have a large amount of data. @AnasMansuri.

Comment: Go to the Network by doing inspect element and see which request is served over http and you need to fix selectively. It might be some third party script causing this which is not visible as per your question

Comment: Yes, I know. I have one HTTP URL. And I want to allow in my page. So is it possible? @ArifAhmad

Comment: are they same domain or different domains?

Comment: Or maybe let me revise my question. Why you need to make it http only? If it is on your control then just change to https. If not then I have another simple solution for you. Just create a page on your server which can be served over https and from that page do another curl request to get the http content. Might not be possible always but just throwing options for you to have more ideas

Comment: are they same domain or different domains? -> Another domain. I want to load the third party URL in my page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94234/discussion-between-dharmik-ponda-and-arif-ahmad).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link for same block HTTP Request an HTTPS page.

[Mixed Content: This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195440/mixed-content-this-request-has-been-blocked-the-content-must-be-served-over-ht?rq=1)