# Mixed Content Can some body help to fix SSL (mixed Content)

Tags: magento2, ssl

analytics.js:44 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ringmastersports.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://192.168.1.7/magento-amsport/magento2/pub/media/emthemes/themesettings/background/blank.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
Kc @ analytics.js:44
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ringmastersports.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://192.168.1.7/magento-amsport/magento2/pub/media/emthemes/themesettings/background/blank.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
blank.gif:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
jquery.js:6631 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ringmastersports.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://192.168.1.7/magento-amsport/magento2/pub/media/emthemes/themesettings/background/blank.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
computeStyleTests @ jquery.js:6631
jquery-migrate.js:41 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.andSelf() replaced by jQuery.fn.addBack()

Comment: I can see the image paths are being called via http and other paths by https. You can update all paths to be called via https to rectify mixed content issue, specially http://192.168.1.7/magento-amsport/magento2/pub/media/emthemes/themesettings/background/blank.gif needs to be called via https path as per above log.

Comment: i can't see any such directory over in my website

Comment: As per the provided log, it seems like it is set as emtheme background image. Please check it carefully if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

try to paste this in your index.php

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

or

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

got it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/19489/73429).

Happy Coding